# Dynamically Setting Max date in jQuery Mobile datebox

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-mobile, datebox

I"m having a heck of a time setting the date for the jQuery Mobile Datebox. I am able to set the end date to "2013-02-14" by setting the "max" attribute in the html tag

```
<input style="color:black" id="date-picker" min="2013-01-24" max="2013-02-14" name="defcal" type="date" data-role="datebox" value=""  id="defcal" data-options='{"mode": "calbox","calTodayButton": true}'/>
```

However if I try to set this attribute programmatically with a selector it doesn't work (refreshing the datebox doesn't seem to help).

I read through the approach linked below which seems extremely convoluted and I wasn't able to implement. Can any one suggest a simple way to do this.

```
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/script/maxdays.html
```

Comment: not a feature yet - but I will look at adding this as a regular option. (I'm guessing that $(element).attr('min', xxxx-xx-xx); does not work? (it probably doesn't ever re-look at that after initialization))

Answer (score 3):

You can now (as of about 10min ago) set min/max attributes then call:

```
$('element').datebox('applyMinMax');
```

to have datebox do all the math for you.  I'd love to have it auto-catch this, but I'm not aware of a way to do this.

Comment: I just downloaded your latest release of the Calbox and core, and it is saying this function does not exist.